# Key mapping on a physical terminal (Teleray 1060) when using getty

Tags: terminal, serial-console, getty

I have an old physical terminal (Teleray 1060) that I am attempting to use as a Linux terminal using getty. I have started a login session just fine. However, my terminal lacks an enter key, having both a carriage return and a line feed key. Neither of these function as an enter key so I am unable to login. Would it be possible to reassign the carriage return to function as an enter key. I am very inexperienced whith Linux.
I am using Xubuntu 20.04.1 and a USB to serial cable.

Ctrl+M works on a virtual terminal.

I tried using Ubuntu 18.04.5 and now it seems to work fine. Is there something that has been changed between the two versions which may affect this?

The command used to start login session:

`systemctl enable serial-getty@007.service --now`

Output of `stty -a` as root on virtual terminal:

````
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ^E; eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany
-imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo``` 

Thanks
````

Comment: Both carriage return and line feed should work as an “enter” key. In fact “enter” is just a nickname for “carriage return”, and carriage return is translated to line feed when reading from a terminal. What model of terminal is it? Do other keys work? What happens when you press the CR and LF keys? Does Ctrl+M or Ctrl+J work as “enter”? Can you run the command `stty -a </dev/ttyS0` (if the path to the terminal device is `/dev/ttyS0`, otherwise replace by the correct path) and post the output?

Comment: Return only sends the cursor back to the start of the line, as does ctrl+M. LF adn ctrl+J sends the cursor directly down. The terminal is a Teleray 1060. When I try the stty command it produces the message: ```stty: 'standard input': Operation not permitted``` Most other keys work. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, then the problem is that the terminal is somehow not seen as a terminal. You need to run the `stty` command as root, sorry, I forgot to mention that. Running `stty` with the right parameters should make the terminal work as a one-off, but I don't know offhand what the parameters would be (and seeing the output of `stty -a` would help). There's probably a getty configuration to be done which would set correct stty settings automatically.

Comment: Sorry, it was too large to fit in one comment. This is the output of the ```stty -a``` command on the virtual terminal. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Hmmm, `eol = ^E`. Does pressing Ctrl+E work as “enter”? Normally `eol = <undef>` should work and have CR be “enter”, but that may hinge on one of the foo/-foo settings below, I don't know which one though: `-inlcr -igncr icrnl` are the ones I can think of and I think these are their normal values.

Comment: Please accept my edit and also includes the type of serial-to-usb adapter (`lsusb`, `readlink -f /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/tty*/driver`)

Comment: The question indicates that the terminal is `/dev/007`, because that's what the service has been run against, but the comments are talking about `/dev/ttyS0` and a virtual terminal.  This isn't a virtual terminal.  It is a _real_ terminal.  Please [edit] the question to indicate that you are dumping the settings of the right device.  _Show exactly what command you ran._

Comment: I tried using Ubuntu 18.04.5 and now it seems to work fine. Is there something that has been changed between the two versions which may affect this? Thanks for the help.